# What is the expected size of the data.mdb file (May 2023)?

Tags: synchronization

Waiting several days for Monero-gui wallet daemon to sync, can anybody tell me the approximate size to expect for the data.mdb file?

Answer (score 1):

An unpruned database ~170 GiB, pruned ~60 GiB.

Answer (score 0):

estimated around under 172GB unpruned database