# How do I connect the Monero daemon to a remote node?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, daemon, full-node, remote-access, remote-node

Not requiring access to the full blockchain, looking to use a remote node as here:

[How do I connect monero-wallet-cli to a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1402/14165)

For the `cli` wallet, how can the daemon be configured to use a remote node?  Perhaps with `set_daemon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I [answered](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/13950/7493) your ([duplicate](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/how-to-configure-the-daemon-to-use-a-remote-node)) question:

> You can't configure a "daemon" to use a remote node, it makes no sense, but you can configure a wallet to use a remote node.