# Does each GUI wallet need to iterate the blockchain for transactions?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, remote-access, remote-node

In context of:

[How to complete synchronization through a remote node?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13952/14165)

[How to install the monero wallet GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1468677/847449)

When the wallet GUI completes so that zero blocks remain, how much overlap is there with other wallets on the same system with the same user?

To my understanding, the GUI will only store transactions relevant for a specific wallet.  Under that configuration, then, the entire blockchain would have to be iterated through again.  Is that correct?

All else being equal, I prefer the `cli` over the `GUI`.  But all else isn't equal, as the `cli` wallet is out of date.

Comment: "But all else isn't equal, as the cli wallet is out of date." So update it. There's no good reason to *not* upgrade to the latest release.

Comment: Absolutely @jtgrassie but apt shows this to be latest version, which is why I went to flatpak.

Comment: "DISCLAIMER: These packages are not part of this repository or maintained by this project's contributors, and as such, do not go through the same review process to ensure their trustworthiness and security." [src](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#installing-monero-from-a-package)

Comment: "but apt shows this to be latest version" <- you didn't install from an official release. See https://www.getmonero.org/downloads/ and https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases for official releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does each GUI wallet need to iterate the blockchain for transactions?

Yes, this is called *scanning*. A wallet can't know if it received any transactions without scanning the blockchain.

> ... how much overlap is there with other wallets on the same system with the same user?

None.

> To my understanding, the GUI will only store transactions relevant for a specific wallet.

Correct.

> ...the entire blockchain would have to be iterated through again. Is that correct?

Not quite. Each wallet keeps track of where in the blockchain it last scanned from, and each must scan from that point, regardless of where *other* wallets have scanned. So if wallet A last scanned from 1 to 100, when it's next loaded, it must scan from 100, and if wallet B hasn't yet scanned anything, it must scan from 1. The wallets are completely independent.

Comment: On Ask Ubuntu, asked how to install v18 of the CLI wallet and daemon https://askubuntu.com/q/1469163/847449

Comment: "DISCLAIMER: These packages are not part of this repository or maintained by this project's contributors, and as such, do not go through the same review process to ensure their trustworthiness and security." [src](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#installing-monero-from-a-package)