# How to free up space from the GUI wallet scanning the blockchain?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, full-node, remote-access, remote-node

I seem to have run into a full hard drive while [scanning](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13953/14165) the blockchain:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat monero.gui/monero-wallet-cli.log 
2023-05-20 10:53:31.795     7f288f9c89c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-20 11:32:51.271     7f75784d29c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-20 17:34:36.110     7f9537cb89c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-20 20:25:56.617     7f7d02c859c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-21 16:23:56.003     7fbc8a3689c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-21 18:02:00.441     7ff89eac19c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-21 19:19:43.251     7f14c5c289c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-21 19:21:12.568     7efe341e59c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-21 19:21:36.719     7f58e06269c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-21 19:22:54.247     7f9ec6d619c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 00:11:42.634     7fe184bd79c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 00:12:27.018     7f641993a9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 00:13:03.026     7fc1f708b9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 00:13:33.955     7fc05f60f9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 01:02:48.930     7f7f09df29c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 01:05:20.354     7f62977df9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 05:03:39.841     7f2a828de9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 05:26:16.792     7f65a5f2d9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 17:18:59.750     7f3ae1de39c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 17:37:16.074     7f481493c9c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
2023-05-22 17:37:38.990     7f838b8e19c0    INFO    logging contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:273   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.http:FATAL,net.ssl:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,daemon.rpc:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,serialization:FATAL,daemon.rpc.payment:ERROR,stacktrace:INFO,logging:INFO,msgwriter:INFO
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ flatpak info org.getmonero.Monero

Monero GUI - Monero: the secure, private, untraceable cryptocurrency

          ID: org.getmonero.Monero
         Ref: app/org.getmonero.Monero/x86_64/stable
        Arch: x86_64
      Branch: stable
     Version: 0.18.2.2
     License: BSD-3-Clause
      Origin: flathub
  Collection: org.flathub.Stable
Installation: system
   Installed: 140.9 MB
     Runtime: org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15-22.08
         Sdk: org.kde.Sdk/x86_64/5.15-22.08

      Commit: e12002e9ff82c6446a107fb31fa5db3ddf93e8b38251f6e288b04db7c472c3b6
      Parent: 9597733eb5c8b8de1d1a0a239c654c5da6dddc15a3bc757874c15903daddf06f
     Subject: build: Update p2pool to 3.3 (96939ce0)
        Date: 2023-05-01 04:44:03 +0000
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                             1.6G  2.6M  1.6G   1% /run
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g                          158G   16G  142G  11% /
tmpfs                                             7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/spool                142G  128K  142G   1% /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/www                  142G  128K  142G   1% /var/www
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/mail                 142G  128K  142G   1% /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/snap                 142G  5.5M  142G   1% /var/snap
rpool/USERDATA/root_96fqhx                        142G   89M  142G   1% /root
rpool/USERDATA/nicholas_96fqhx                    187G   45G  142G  25% /home/nicholas
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/log                  143G  797M  142G   1% /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/lib                  159G   18G  142G  11% /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/games                142G  128K  142G   1% /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/srv                      142G  128K  142G   1% /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/usr/local                142G  128K  142G   1% /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/lib/NetworkManager   142G  256K  142G   1% /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/lib/apt              142G   95M  142G   1% /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/lib/AccountsService  142G  128K  142G   1% /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_h54u9g/var/lib/dpkg             142G   49M  142G   1% /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/var/lib/docker                              142G  2.2M  142G   1% /var/lib/docker
tmpfs                                             7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /run/qemu
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_h54u9g                          1.8G  289M  1.5G  17% /boot
/dev/sda2                                         512M   16M  497M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs                                             1.6G  192K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                                             1.6G  104K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1014
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

While I recall selecting to only store a few transactions, I'm not seeing anything about this in the GUI at the moment.

Where is this setting found?
Where is the data being stored?
How much data is being stored?
How would I manually, or through the GUI, free up some working hard drive space?

How much space does a wallet with with ten transactions require?

So far as I'm aware, the GUI has been connecting to a remote node so shouldn't require much local storage for these transactions at all.

```
nicholas@mordor:~/Monero/wallets/monero_gui$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/Monero/wallets/monero_gui$ ls -alh
total 27M
drwx------ 2 nicholas nicholas    6 May 23 19:14 .
drwx------ 5 nicholas nicholas    5 May 23 19:21 ..
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 9.9M May 23 19:14 monero_gui
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 1.7K May 23 18:59 monero_gui.keys
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas 5.5M May 22 20:47 monero_gui.old_cache
-rw------- 1 nicholas nicholas  12M May 22 20:48 monero_gui.old_cache.1
nicholas@mordor:~/Monero/wallets/monero_gui$
```

I'm certainly not seeing any large files.  Possibly my hard drive was full already, but I find that doubtful.  For starters, I'd like to see how much storage any wallets are using.

I had selected the "simple mode" for the GUI wallet, but perhaps need to manually enter a `--prune-blockchain` command?