# How to prune the blockchain for GUI wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, wallet-recovery, remote-node, pruning

Towards recovering a wallet with less than ten transactions, looking to run the `--prune-blockchain` flag [within](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/13956/14165) the GUI.

I'm selecting options as:

> Simple mode Easy access to sending, receiving and basic functionality.

Explicitly *not* selecting:

> Simple mode (bootstrap) Easy access to sending, receiving and basic
> functionality.  The blockchain is downloaded to your computer.

Even in the advanced mode options there are no options for manually entering such flags, at least that I see.